# Angular: most elegant, shortest way to use a translation pipe in your component (TS code)

Tags: angular, translation

So, I have a translation pipe, is pretty mush self explanatory

```
import { TranslationService } from 'app/services/translation.service';
const getByKey = require('lodash.get');

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate'
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public _translation: TranslationService) {}

  transform(value: string, args?: string): string {
    return getByKey(this._translation.store, value) || args;
  }
}
```

what I would like is to use this pipe in my components BUT, I would like it to be elegant and not too instrusive

don't want to end up with the code like this:

```
constructor(private _T: TranslatePipe) {
  ....
  this.testText = this._T.transform('mylong.andlengthy.section.key', 'Fall back english text');
  ....
}
```

What I would like instead is to do something like

```
const _T = require('app/pipes/translate.pipe)'; // or something that would work with import
```

on top

and then to use it like

```
constructor() {
      ....
      this.testText = _T('mylong.andlengthy.section.key', 'Fall back english text');
      ....
    }
```

Any good suggestions

Comment: You are using the pipes in wrong way i guess, could please visit the following link https://alligator.io/angular/custom-pipes-angular/

Comment: you guess wrong @Nour ... we are using the pipes in the view the correct way... we also have to do the translations in the component code.... and we wanted to reuse the same logic...

Comment: Using pipes anywhere but the view is not the correct way. You already have same logic to reuse. It's TranslationService. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are supposed to be used in component templates. Properly designed pipe should be a shallow wrapper for underlying services, also providing view-specific features if necessary, such as change detection.

This is an example of properly designed pipe. The proper way to get a translation programmatically is to call the service directly, similarly to what's done in pipe `transform` method:

```
const getByKey = require('lodash.get');
...
translatedValue = getByKey(translationService.store, value);
```

The fact that it needs to use Lodash `get` every time and directly access `store` indicates that the service misses `get` method to keep it DRY and encapsulate `store`. It should be refactored to be

```
return translationService.getWithOptionalFallback(value, args);
```

in the pipe, and

```
translatedValue = translationService.getWithOptionalFallback(value);
```

anywhere else.

The only time when programmatic pipe access is appropriate is when third-party pipes weren't properly designed and contain functionality that cannot be reached in another way (namely Angular built-in pipes). In this case pipe class is manually instantiated and `transform` method is called. This usage is undocumented and may not work as expected or not work at all, depending on particular pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I just build an application with different languages and I can strongly recommend the ngs-translation modul:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Its very easy to use, you find all the documentation on GitHub.

You store all your translations in key-value pairs in a .json file. For example:

```
{
  "HELLO": "Welcome to my application"
}
```

In your template you can call:

`<div>{{ 'HELLO' | translate }}</div>`

and it would print out: 
`<div>Welcome to my application</div>`

I know thats not exactly what you where asking for, but I hope its helpful to you

Comment: it is not what I am asking for... we are using the translate pipe the similar way... we just need a way to reuse the pipe logic we use in the view.... reuse it in the component as well